# How to prevent VS Code from auto importing when using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code for Unity script editing. I've updated my settings.json file with these lines:

```
"[csharp]": {
    "brace_style": "collapse,preserve-inline",
    "suggest.autoImports": false
},
```

which has changed its brace style for me, but the autoImports / autoUsing behavior remains the same. This is probably because I'm using the closest thing I could find from the JavaScript settings to prevent it.

My reason for wishing to prevent this behavior is that every time I start using any of Unity's Debug class, VS Code auto adds `using System.Diagnostics;` which is not at all appropriate and I'd rather just prevent the thing from getting in my way.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had AutoUsing as an extension enabled. Disabling that extension and restarting the editor solved this problem for me.